# Django Switching to New Database (locally)

Tags: database, django, postgresql

Oh my local test for Django I am attempting to switch my default local database from an old SQLLite database to a Postgres database to mimic my live environment hosted through heroku. To do this I have the postgres database locally and I changed all my settings.py as shown below, but Django does not recognize that the DB exists. In addition to this, if I run migrate or syncdb it still tries to recreate the old sqllite3 database. Anybody have any experience with this change from one database to another and see any similar problems?

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'postgres',                      
    # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'myusername',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Still learning the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using a wrong settings file, or have something like local_settings.py that overrides your settings, or have duplicate `DATABASES` entries in your settings.  Execute:

```
python manage.py diffsettings
```

Do you see the correct `DATABASES` settings there?

Comment: I did not, but I'm not sure where that could be coming from as I don't have another settings file. Could it have anything to do with git branching causing the problem?

Comment: Something is not right in your configuration.  In your manage.py, `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` should include the module name of your settings.py, for example `myproj.settings`.

Comment: Its correctly listed under the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. I'm completely stumped why it might be hanging on to the old settings.

Comment: delete all your `.pyc` files. They are cached compiled versions of your `.py` files.

Comment: Just tried that and unfortunately they seem to recreate themselves immediatly afterwards and it does not solve the problem. I have a feeling I'm doing something really stupid here...

Comment: upload the whole folder to git, and send a link.

Comment: It turns out I am an idiot. There was a stray line of code further down in settings that was conflicting. Thanks for the help!